# python path problem: ImportError when calling zodbconvert (FreeBSD 8.1)

Tags: python, plone, relstorage

I guess this is a python path problem (on FreeBSD 8.1).

Im trying to convert a Data.fs to Postgresql using zodbconvert. Ive downloaded RelStorage-1.5.0b2 and is running:

```
/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.6/bin/python zodbconvert.py fstodb.conf
```

, to use the version that Plone is running with.

The error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zodbconvert.py", line 22, in <module>
    from persistent.TimeStamp import TimeStamp
ImportError: No module named persistent.TimeStamp
```

Versions:

- Plone 4.0.5 (python 2.6)
- Postgresql 9.0.3
- FreeBSD 8.1
- python26-2.6.6_1
- python27-2.7.1_1

PS by default "python --version" is 2.7.1

Thanks.
Nikolaj G.

Comment: And *can* you import it?

Comment: sorry, im new in here - of course. thanks. nikolaj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `buildout` (I do hope you are) the easiest way to get all the `zodbconvert` dependencies properly included in the python path is to have `buildout` create the script for you:

```
[buildout]
...
parts =
     ...
     zodbconvert

[zodbconvert]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
scripts = zodbconvert
```

Buildout then will create a new `bin/zodbconvert` script for you that includes all the buildout eggs in `sys.path`.

Alternatively, you can create a generic python script runner that includes all eggs in your buildout and can run arbitrary scripts; you can use this instead of the bare-bones python interpreter to run arbitrary python scripts with all the buildout eggs in `sys.path`:

```
[buildout]
...
parts =
    ...
    zopepy

[zopepy]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
interpreter = zopepy
scripts = zopepy
```

The `bin/zopepy` script can then be use to run arbitrary python scripts with all your buildout eggs already in `sys.path`, so `bin/zopepy zodbconvert.py fstodb.conf` should work.

Note that the Plone unified installer already comes with the `zopepy` part included, and my choice of partname for this script was deliberately using the same name.

If you are not using `buildout` (and with Plone 4, that's not a good idea on the whole), you can also list the required packages (ZODB3, zope.interface, RelStorage, psycopg2) in your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

quick fix..

```
locate persistent
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/your/python_persistent_dir
```

Comment: He'll need to include the `ZODB`, `zope.interface`, `RelStorage`, and `psycopg2` packages as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have not included the **ZODB** package with your Python installation. Either adjust the PYTHONPATH to include the **ZODB** package or just `easy_install ZODB` - depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: He'll need more than the ZODB; he'll miss out on `psycopg2`, `RelStorage` and `zope.interface`. Better just to go with bin/zopepy or a dedicated buildout part, not? :-)

Comment: Thanks Sentinel, Ill try it out. Sorry about the "accept thing" - I just gave you a point. Ill get back to the problem - a bit stressed at the moment. Thanks.